# ENOTDIR: Not a directory error when including certain Python Packages and using Serverless Deploy

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Certain Python packages that I try to include (eg. CFFI, Google API core) throw an error (ENOTDIR: not a directory, scan dir /path/from/to/packagename) when I run Serverless Deploy. It seems that certain packages don’t have a directory structure and try to expand in the project directory during build time and throw this error.

Have banged my head against the wall on this now for a while - Anyone have any idea how to correct this? I’m building for AWS Lambda using Python3.8.

Thank you!

Assumed that this was something to do with my project structure, but other packages seem to work fine. Have tried re-creating a virtual environment and many, many different configurations of serverless.yml to no avail :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.